# mysqldump con crono genera un archivo vacio

Tags: cron, crontab

Tengo el siguiente comando:

```
mysqldump -h216.70.69.75 -uivanchido -pFlystar3979@@@ bdivan > /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/jamoncitoi1.sql
```

El cual me genera un archivo de nombre `jamoncitoi1.sql` con el respaldo de la BD y funciona correctamente.

Cuando intento ejecutar el mismo comando mediante cron editando `crontab -e` mediante esta forma:

```
*/1 * * * * mysqldump -h216.70.69.75 -uivanchido -pFlystar3979@@@ bdivan > /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/jamoncitoi1.sql
```

Me genera el mismo archivo pero me lo pone vacío.

No sé por que razón....

Noto que cron me envia correos diciendo que el comando `mysqldump` no pudo ser encontrado pero el comando:

echo `$PATH` me arroja:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

lo cual es correcto por que si contiene la ruta al comando.

Alguien me pudiera orientar que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Gracias.

Comment: El path de crontab no es el path de tu sesión.

Comment: ¿Cómo se sabe cuál es el path del crontab y cuál es el path de mi sesión?

Comment: El path de tu sesión lo da `echo $PATH`. Para crontab, no sé; siempro uso paths completos.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta indicando la ruta completa del comando `mysqldump`:

Con el comando `which` puedes obtenerlo:

```
$ -> which mysqldump
/usr/bin/mysqldump
```

Con lo que pasaría a estar así:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -h216.70.69.75 -uivanchido -pFlystar3979@@@ bdivan > /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/jamoncitoi1.sql
```

También, podrías hacerlo mediante un script, por ejemplo, `realizar_backup.sh`, con el siguiente contenido:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mysqldump -h216.70.69.75 -uivanchido -pFlystar3979@@@ bdivan > /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/jamoncitoi1.sql
```

Y añadir en el cron:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/usuario/ruta/realizar_backup.sh
```

Y si necesitas guardar `logs`:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/usuario/ruta/realizar_backup.sh > /home/usuario/ruta/backup.log 2>&1
```

- **`2>&1`**: con esto rediriges si da error al mismo descriptor donde apunta la salida estándar por lo que irá todo a `backup.log`.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas, gracias lo voy a intentar, wich no se que hace, pero lo investigaré, gracias!

Comment: Which lo que hace es devolverte la ruta para saber cómo debe ser ejecutado en tu entorno. Cuando escribes el comando `ls`, por ejemplo, realmente estás llamando a `/bin/ls`. Y así como todos los comandos. Espero te funcione el cron, ya nos lo comentarás.

Comment: Se necesita algo para que el script si se ejecute?? por que cuando lo hago por script no parece ejecutarse

Comment: Dale permisos al script `chmod +x realizar_backup.sh`  luego intenta ejecutarlo a mano: `/home/usuario/ruta/realizar_backup.sh` o `/bin/bash /home/usuario/ruta/realizar_backup.sh` si usas bash. No deberías tener problema para ejecutarlo.

Comment: la situación del script esta así:

Comment: -rw-r--r--@  1 ivancaballerocano  staff   119 Oct  6 11:57 scri

Comment: ya cambió a: -rwxr-xr-x@  1 ivancaballerocano  staff   119 Oct  6 11:57 scri

Comment: sh: /Users/ivancaballerocano/scri.sh: No such file or directory  :(

Comment: Parece que no estás llamando correctamente al fichero al momento de la ejecución, porque aquí veo que te ha funcionado bien añadir código a un script y ejecutarlo: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395259/porqu%C3%A9-un-comando-que-si-jala-directo-en-la-terminal-no-funciona-en-cron/395263]