# ¿Porqué un comando que si jala directo en la terminal no funciona en cron?

Tags: cron

Tengo el siguiente comando en el crontab:

```
*/2 * * * * consulta.sh
```

El cual provoca que se ejecute el script `consulta.sh` cada 2 minutos.

El script consulta.sh contiene las siguientes líneas:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script de ejemplo
FINAL_OUTPUT=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")
sudo ls -l / > archivoResultado_$FINAL_OUTPUT
```

Si mando ejecutar el script directamente con el comando: `sh consulta.sh` funciona correctamente y si me genera el archivo de salida:

```
archivoResultado_$FINAL_OUTPUT
```

Pero tengo el problema de que el cron no me esta ejecutando el script y no tengo idea de por que no funciona. ¿Alguna orientación?

Gracias

Comment: normalmente en crones tienes que poner la ruta absoluta del archivo, dónde tienes el archivo `consulta.sh`? intenta poner la ruta absoluta

Comment: lo tengo en /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/

Comment: pues ya lo cambie a: */2 * * * * /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/consulta.sh. y no funcionó de todos modos

Answer (score 1):

Al igual que te comenté en la siguiente pregunta: [mysqldump con crono genera un archivo vacio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395067/mysqldump-con-crono-genera-un-archivo-vacio)

Tienes que colocar la ruta completa donde se encuentre el fichero:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/usuario/ruta/consulta.sh
```

En tu caso estás pasando un fichero como si fuese una ruta relativa o te encontraras en el mismo directorio que él. Tendrías que pasarlo como ruta absoluta.

- [Diferencia ruta relativa y ruta absoluta](https://denovatoanovato.net/rutas-relativas-y-rutas-absolutas/)

Comment: pues ya lo cambie a: */2 * * * * /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/consulta.sh.  y no funcionó de todos modos

Comment: Estás teniendo problema con todas las tareas programadas, ninguna se te está ejecutando así que vamos paso por paso a ver si logramos resolverlo. Ejecuta, por favor, el comando `which touch`, y lo que te devuelva (por ejemplo a mí me devuelve `/usr/bin/touch`) lo añades al crontab de la siguiente manera: `* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /Users/ivancaballerocano/test.txt` (no debería hacer falta colocar `/usr/bin` porque debería estar dentro del PATH, pero por si acaso) y al cabo de un minuto verifica si te creó un fichero vacío llamado `test.txt` en la carpeta `/Users/ivancaballerocano/`.

Comment: Luego por las rutas que tienes, ¿estás usando algo similar a lo siguiente? [https://medium.com/@rodritorrico/tutorial-como-activar-la-terminal-de-linux-en-windows-10-beta-52769b5cab7e]

Comment: este es mi crontab: (La tarea donde mando llamar un script es la que NO hace, la segunda si funciona en tiempo y forma)

Comment: */2 * * * * /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/consulta.sh

Comment: */2 * * * *  /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump -h216.70.69.75 -uivanchido -pFlystar3979@@@ bdivan > /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/respaldoFijo.sql

Comment: which touch  me devuelve  /usr/bin/touch

Comment: Ah no si ya jaló con el touch

Comment: Parece que el problema es con `sudo`. Elimina del script la palabra `sudo`. No deberías tener problema para listar el contenido de raíz. Está todo en modo lectura. A menos que tengas algún permiso de lectura eliminado para todos los usuarios a excepción de root. Normalmente `sudo` te pide contraseña. De allí a que en el `cron` no funcione.

Comment: hace rato ya le había quitado el "sudo", el experimento con touch si funcionó. Sigue sin jalar el */2 * * * * /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/consulta.sh

Comment: Es extraño. Si haces un `ls /` te debe arrojar resultados. Por lo que si quitas `sudo` no deberías tener problema.

Comment: Quizás esto tenga algún error:

Comment: ls -l / > /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/jamononqueso.txt